# Thermodynamics, pressure volume work

Tags: thermodynamics

In thermodynamics work done by the system is negative but in case of expansion of gas it is positive because force and displacement are in same direction, why?

Comment: Because force and displacement are in same direction, just like you said. Really, what a strange kind of science the thermodynamics would be if the work were always negative?

Comment: But it should be negative as per convention adopted

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The system does positive work. Textbooks introduce the negative to show that the system loses energy as it does expansion work. As the gas expands, it does positive work but it loses this energy in the process. Work, like heat, is basically a transfer of energy.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is due to pressure which is negative in the pressure volume work equation actually here two types of pressure act at a time one is external other is internal so net effect of external is less then internal which is taken negative.

Comment: Your very long answer including just one sentence is not easy to read. Could you split it up into shorter sentences?