# Principles of Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

A gas expands and does 82.7 J of work on the surroundings. At the same time, the gas loses 103 J of energy to the surroundings as heat. What is the change in the internal energy of the gas? 
would this be ΔE = q + w  (-103) + (82.7) = -20.3.   I get confused with the positive and negative charges.

Comment: Ignore the heat part first. If the gas does work on its surroundings, do you think its energy increases or decreases? If you push a block of metal, does your energy increase or decrease?

Comment: This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Comment: Related: [Thermodynamics, pressure volume work](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37240/7951)

Answer (score 1):

The standardized definition of the change in internal energy $U$ for a closed thermodynamic system is

$$\Delta U = Q + W$$

where $Q$ is amount of heat transferred *to the system* and $W$ is work done *on the system* (provided that no chemical reactions occur).

Therefore, heat transferred *from the surroundings to the system* is assigned a positive sign in the equation, whereas heat transferred *from the system to the surroundings* is assigned a negative sign.

Similarly, work done *by the surroundings on the system* is assigned a positive sign in the equation, whereas work done *by the system on the surroundings* is assigned a negative sign.

(Note that some books on physics or engineering still use a non-standard definition when discussing the work done by a thermodynamic heat engine.)